# how do I stop the header of my search results from being highlighted on mouseover

Tags: css

I'm using the following css to highlight my data rows

```
tr:hover{
background-color:grey;
}
```

but this highlights the table header as well.

I tried

```
.notfirst:hover{
background-color:grey;
}
```

but that prevents anything from highlighting.  Is there a simple css fix to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
tr:hover:not(:first-child) {
background-color:grey;
}
```

Comment: I posted mine before any answers were visible

Comment: @user2447848 He/she didn't; they were 1 minute 32 seconds faster, that's all.

Comment: @user2447848 Timestamps say he/she still outraced your comment by 13 seconds (07:18:57 v 07:19:10).

Comment: @user2447848 my bad, I saw my answer post before anything else so I assumed wrong. I apologize I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    //styles here
}
```